# how to view the answer of a js function in a html input?

Tags: javascript, html, input

I've always been wondering this, but all websites seem to be answering the opposite (how to make text typed in an input be the input of a function).
Is there a way to do it?

Comment: give us an example of a code, a scenario etc. and what you have tried..

Comment: `someInput.value = aFunction();` ... I doubt you [couldn't find any information](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+set+text+input&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) in the entire Web about setting values of form inputs fields.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want to do?

```
function myFunction() {
    // some functionality here
    // this function must return something
}

var input = document.querySelector('input');
input.value = myFunction();
```

This will set the value of the `input` element to the value returned by `myFunction`.

Comment: Yes, that is what I want to do